# Modify Feedback Workflow to transfer a custom column value from Shared Documents to the Tasks list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks

I would like to modify the default feedback workflow. I have already made a copy of the workflow and made some minor adjustments to fit my needs. Now I need the work flow to pull the information from a custom column in the Shared Documents library (project), to the task list. This way when the workflow assigns someone to provide feedback to a document, the task will be tagged with the same project the original document was tagged with.

I am a novice to workflows and getting more familiar with SharePoint 2010. Any help or advise is appreciated, thanks.